# Conforme fosse digitando no campo input aparecesse o os radios button abaixo

Tags: javascript

Eu fiz o seguinte código para quando fosse digitando no campo input aparecesse os radio buttons abaixo mas não funciona, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
$('#amount').onchange('input', function(){
    var dinheiro = $(this).val();
    if (dinheiro <= 5) {
      $("#valArrecadar").show();
      $("#valArrecadar2").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar3").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar4").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar5").hide();  
    } else if (dinheiro <=10) {
      $("#valArrecadar").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar2").show();
      $("#valArrecadar3").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar4").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar5").hide()
    } else if (dinheiro <=25) {
      $("#valArrecadar").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar2").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar3").show();
      $("#valArrecadar4").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar5").hide()
    }else if (dinheiro <=50) {
      $("#valArrecadar").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar2").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar3").hide();
      $("#valArrecadar4").show();
      $("#valArrecadar5").hide()
    }
  });
```

Comment: O evento `onchange` só vai dar trigger quando você tirar o foco do input. Tenta usar `keyup` no lugar.

Comment: @Churrozz, você precisa melhorar o título da sua pergunta. Está confuso

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!

Comment: Este evento `onchange` não existe no **jQuery** isto é do **Javascript**. O do jQuery seria `$('#amount').on('change', function...)` ou então `$('#amount').change(function...)`

Comment: @LeAndrade Entendi, eu sou novo e acabo me confundindo na hora de saber se é javascript ou jquery

Comment: Joia man. Outra coisa sei que está apenas começando mas na programação sempre é bom tender a criar menos código possível, incluindo repetições, a programação tem sua base exatamente sobre este ponto. Diminuir trabalhos repetitivos. Na sua função não precisa deste monte de **hide()**, uma forma de se fazer isto é dar `hide()` em tudo que não seja o elemento que se quer dar `show()`.